# How to validate whether a word in a dataframe is a name in R

Tags: r, dataframe, count

I have written a R script that filters data and saves it to a new data frame. Among other things, it filters the most frequently used word as follows:

```
Word     Times
Oliver    3
Great     8
Jacob     2
Fantastic 6
```

Is there a way in R to filter the last data frame to look like this given a list of names?

(That takes the names, count them, and then add them to a new row named names that counts the times all the names appeared)

```
Word     Times
Names     5 # Oliver [3] + Jacob [2]
Great     8
Fantastic 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `x` instead of `names`.

Base `R` way

```
x <-  c('oliver','jacob','harry', 'jack')

y <- sum(df$Times[df$Word %in% x])
rbind(c("names", y), df[!(df$Word %in% x), ])

       Word Times
1     names     5
2     great     8
4 fantastic     6
```

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` solution

```
names <- c('oliver','jacob','harry', 'jack')

df %>% 
     summarize_each(funs(ifelse(Word %in% names, "names", .))) %>%
     group_by(Word) %>% 
     summarize(sum(Times))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Word      `sum(Times)`
  <chr>            <dbl>
1 fantastic            6
2 great                8
3 names                5
```